# Не отправляется push-уведомление когда приложение закрыто

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

Согласно [документации](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/notifications), никаких дополнительных настроек в android не требуется. Нужно лишь инициализировать firebase:

```
await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
);
```

Когда приложение открыто или свернуто, то все приходит и обрабатывается. Но если приложение полностью закрыто, уведомления не доходят. Настройки телефона проверены, все уведомления разрешены.

Данные уведомления:

```
{
    "to":"token",
    "notification":{"title":"Title","body":"Body"},
}
```

Comment: Что значит `приложение полностью закрыто`? Если вы принудительную остановку ему сделали, то работать не будет ничто и никогда до тех пор пока приложение явно юзером не будет запущено. В теории такую принудительную остановку могут и разные оболочки делать и производители. Возможно, вам стоит на других девайсах проверить.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб "Что значит приложение полностью закрыто?" - если смахнуть его в списке приложений. При принудительной остановке ничего не должно работать, согласен. Но при смахивании должно, об этом написано в документации. Проверил на нескольких смартфонах разных брендов, не работает.

Comment: Попробуйте что-то из этих ответов: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57054706/flutter-fcm-is-not-working-when-app-is-closed/66352890 Например запустить на эмуляторе, а не на реальном девайсе и поковырять системные настройки приложения в части настроек уведомлений и автозапуска

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Да, действительно. Добавил приложение в вишлист энергосберегающей системы и пуши стали приходить. Но как тогда отправляются уведомления от других приложений сторонних разработчиков. И есть не очень популярные приложения, от них мы же как-то получаем уведомления, но в вишлист я их не добовлял.

Comment: В некоторых пуш-системах можно договориться с провайдером пушей на отправку высокоприоритетных пушей. Они, видимо, могут обходить подобного рода ограничения. При этом не обязательно быть лицокнигой. Но надо доказывать что вам такие пуши нужны. Ну и не ясно какие именно вы приложения читаете не очень популярными. Возможно они более популярны чем вы думаете или договорились с провайдером пушей или просто имеют настолько устаревший код, что на них не распространяются ограничения ОС. Если техническое решение придумывать - можно попробовать какую-то периодическую фоновую задачу запускать. Но это хз